# Error executing cursor.execute when quotes are required

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

fairly new to SQL in general. I'm currently trying to bolster my general understanding of how to pass commands via `cursor.execute()`. I'm currently trying to grab a column from a table and rename it to something different.

```
import mysql.connector

user = 'root'
pw = 'test!*'
host =  'localhost'
db =  'test1'

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pw, host=host, database=db)
cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)
new_name = 'Company Name'
query = f'SELECT company_name AS {new_name} from company_directory'
cursor.execute(query)
fetch = cursor.fetchall()
```

I've also tried it like this:

```
query = 'SELECT company_name AS %s from company_directory'
cursor.execute(query, ('Company Name'),)
fetch = cursor.fetchall()
```

but that returns the following error:

```
stmt = self._cmysql.stmt_prepare(statement)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? from company_directory' at line 1
```

I'm using python and mySQL. I keep reading about database injection and not using string concatenation but every time I try to use `%s` I get an error similar to the one below where. I've tried switching to `?` syntax but i get the same error.

If someone could ELI5 what the difference is and what exactly database injection is and if what I'm doing in the first attempt qualifies as string concatenation that I should be trying to avoid.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you need to rename it? `cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, unless you use `dictionary=True` when creating the cursor, so the column names aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

If a column name or alias contains spaces, you need to put it in backticks.

```
query = f'SELECT company_name AS `{new_name}` from company_directory'
```

You can't use a placeholder for identifiers like table and column names or aliases, only where expressions are allowed.

Comment: ok got it, so is the above considered string concatenation? and can you give me an example of what expression a placeholder can be used with if you have a minute?

Comment: You can use in places like `WHERE company_name = %s`. That's an expression.

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent to string concatenation. If `new_name` is a user-supplied variable you need to validate it to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: ok thank you - understand. so anytime a user provides a variable (essentially for column names, table names etc, use placeholders otherwise, it's ok to use {}

Comment: In the MariaDB console, single quote, double quotes and backticks all work for me - so using DB-API parameter substitution works, FWIW.

Comment: It won't work with `prepared=True` because that pushes the parameter substitution to the server, and it doesn't allow parameters there. That's why you got the syntax error when you tried it.

Comment: @novawaly, ...in most applications, users aren't allowed to specify column name / table name / etc; it's not a common usage mode to have that level of parameterization exposed. But if you make sure that what they're providing _really is_ a valid column name or table name and not a string that adds extra clauses &c to your query (maybe in addition to containing a valid name), then you can get away with the concatenation approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a query parameter in place of a column alias. The rules for column aliases are the same as column identifiers, and they must be fixed in the query before you pass the query string.

So you could do this:

```
query = f"SELECT company_name AS `{'Company Name'}` from company_directory'
cursor.execute(query)
```